# Making spaghetti plot with different variables as timepoints

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been stuck on this problem for awhile now. I'm trying to create a spaghetti plot where different timepoints are actually different variables (or columns) so the variables are something like: `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Test4` where each test is a different timepoint (and would need to be represented in the x-axis). My y-axis would be the test scores on each test, and I need to plot those by ID's of students over the 4 timepoints.

I tried using `ggplot` and `interaction.plot` command in `R`, but when I use ggplot I get the following error message:

> Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the data.

Same thing with the interaction.plot command, it keeps telling me that arguments have the same length.

Data is in the format:

```
   ID Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4  
   1  83    84    67    44  
   2  67    55    58    59  
   3  99    98    98    95
```

where I need Test1-4 as timepoints and actual scores as the y-axis. And the groups would be the ID's.

I can't post the exact data due to confidentiality issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply use `matplot`

```
# Create some data
df <- data.frame(ID=1:10, Test1=sample(50:100, 10), 
                 Test2=sample(50:100, 10), Test3=sample(50:100, 10))
# Plot it! We remove the ID column, which we don't need to plot
matplot(t(df)[-1,], t="l", lty=1, las=1, ylab="Score", 
        xlab="Test", xaxt="n")
# Use the column labels as axis titles
axis(1, at=1:(ncol(df)-1), labels=names(df)[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

In `ggplot` your data needs to be in a long format. So first you need to reshape the data.

```
library(reshape2)

# melt data from wide to long format
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "ID")

# plot
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = ID, colour = factor(ID))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.csv(text="
ID, Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4
1, 83, 84, 67, 44
2, 67, 55, 58, 59
3, 99, 98, 98, 95
")
#blank plot
plot(0,0,ylim=c(0,100),xlim=c(1,4),bty="n")
#add lines for each ID
for(i in df$ID) lines(1:(ncol(df)-1),
                      df[df$ID==i,2:ncol(df)])
```

[image]